# Are Java Socket shutdownOutput and shutdownInput responsible for "Duplicate ACK #: 1"

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient

At first, I am sorry for long explanation of the below issue.

I have a simple TCP client. Here is the code snippet:

```
        ......
        ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
     .  .....
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        ......
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        .....
        while(r=bufferedReader.read()!-1){
            Reading the response
        }
        socket.shutdownInput();
        .......

        socket.close();
```

My TCP client works with multiple TCP servers except one particular TCP server. My TCP client does not get response from that server in the morning and afternoon (server pick hour time) but get response perfectly without any problem in the evening, night and early morning.

Therefore, I have used the WireShark to inspect the packet of the network during the server pick hour time.

The inspection snippet of the WireShark in the pick hour:

```
4   0.072547    CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC         SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS         TCP      66                clientPort > serverPort [FIN, ACK] Seq=2008 Ack=1 Win=14720 Len=0 TSval=992536 TSecr=4189227564

....

....

7   0.156504    SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS  CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC    TCP 66      serverPort > clientPort [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1449 Win=8704 Len=0 TSval=332931140 TSecr=259206577


8   0.159312    SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS  CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC    TCP 78      [TCP Dup ACK 7#1] serverPort > clientPort [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1449 Win=8704 Len=0 TSval=332931141 TSecr=259206577 SLE=2008 SRE=2009

    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [TCP Analysis Flags]
            [This is a TCP duplicate ack]
        [Duplicate ACK #: 1]
        [Duplicate to the ACK in frame: 7]
            [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): Duplicate ACK (#1)]
                [Message: Duplicate ACK (#1)]
                [Severity level: Note]
                [Group: Sequence]

Note: SSS.SSS.SSS.SSS is server ip and CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC is client ip
```

- Is it problem of TCP server? OR Are socket.shutdownOutput() and socket.shutdownInput() responsible for duplicate ACK?

I am not sure where is the problem because other server is OK with my TCP client (with shutdownOuput and shutdownInput) and that particular server not responding during pick hour 
(morning and afternoon) time only but working other time.

I would be glad, if someone kindly suggests me about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it problem of TCP server?

The problem is probably with the intervening network dropping packets.

> Are socket.shutdownOutput() and socket.shutdownInput() responsible for duplicate ACK?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That particular TCP server, as I mentioned, does not send any further response when duplicate ACK is occurred. Is security monitoring tool on the server side stopping the response? Other TCP servers are OK, even when duplicate ACK is occurred.

Comment: This is getting off-topic. You'd be better off asking at superuser.com or networkengineering.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com.